# Roslyn, how to get all Classes

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn

How can I get all the classes from a Roslyn compilation?

```
var sln = Path.Combine(path, "xxx.sln");

var workspace   = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution    = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(sln);
var project     = solution.Projects.First(x => x.Name == "bbb");
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I visit all the classes in my solution.

```
class ClassVirtualizationVisitor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{   
    List<string> classes = new List<String>();
    
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        node = (ClassDeclarationSyntax) base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    
        string className = node.Identifier.ValueText;
        classes.Add(className); // save your visited classes
                
        return node;
    }
}
```

Now use the visited classes:

```
var classVisitor = new ClassVirtualizationVisitor();
classVisitor.Visit(semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot());
    
var classes = classVisitor.classes; // list of classes in your solution
```

Comment: semanticModel is missing definition, where or how to initialise that ?

Answer (score 6):

This now is my working Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Kardex.LC3xx.CreateApiDokumentation
    {
        //Patch to work with VS2013
        //  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005

        class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Run(args).Wait();

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private async static Task Run(string[] args)
            {
                var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof (Program).Assembly.Location);
                var sln = Path.Combine(path, "xxx.sln");

                var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
                var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(sln);


                Project project = solution.Projects.First(x => x.Name == "bbbb");
                var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

                foreach (var @class in compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers().SelectMany(x=>x.GetMembers()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(@class.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(@class.ContainingNamespace.Name);
                }

                var classVisitor = new ClassVirtualizationVisitor();

                foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
                {
                    classVisitor.Visit(syntaxTree.GetRoot());                
                }

                var classes = classVisitor.Classes;             
            }

            class ClassVirtualizationVisitor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
            {
                public ClassVirtualizationVisitor()
                {
                    Classes = new List<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
                }

                public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> Classes { get; set; }

                public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
                {
                    node = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
                    Classes.Add(node); // save your visited classes
                    return node;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a [SymbolVisitor](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/SymbolVisitor.cs,650e8dd480b0fd0f) that overrides `VisitNamedType` to process each type (which may not be a class).

Then, pass it to `compilation.Assembly.Accept()`.

Comment: I don't think `SymbolVisitor` "walks" the hierarchy, so the user will also have to walk the hierarchy by overriding `VisitAssembly` and `VisitNamespace` as well, right?